# Как выполнять код отдельно от форм

Tags: c#, winforms

Изначально, когда создаешь проект (а именно Приложение Windows Forms), доступен для редактирования файл Form1.cs. Есть необходимость в создании отдельного кода, который будет иметь связь со всем формами, при этом он должен работать независимо от них, даже при закрытии любой формы, но завершаться при закрытии всех форм.

Comment: Если правильно понял, то добавь свой класс в проект. В нем пишешь вою логику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый проект имеет свою точку входа и WinForms не исключение, помимо одной формы по умолчанию также создается класс `Program` и в нем метод `static void Main()` - именно с него приложение начинает свою работу, там же вы и увидите открытие окна: `Application.Run(new Form1());`

Вы можете добавить в этот метод свою логику, какие-то статические публичные свойства и методы в класс `Program` и будете иметь доступ к ним из любого места.

Например, пусть у нас есть некий класс `Data`, содержащий некие данные, которые могут потребоваться в любом месте приложения, добавим в класс `Program` свойство:

```
public static Data AppData { get; private set; }
```

и в методе `Main()` запишем в это свойство некоторое значение:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    AppData = new Data(...);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Теперь из любого места в приложении мы можем получить эти данные:

```
var veryImportantData = Program.AppData....;
```